# How to create mapping relationship using Fluent NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

How can I map one-to-many relationship with 
User to Address,
Customer to Address,
Agency to Address and
store in a single Address Table using Fluent NHibernate

```
public class User
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Address> Address { get; set; }
}
public class Customer
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Address> Address { get; set; }
}
public class Agency
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Address> Address { get; set; }
}
public class Address
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Address2 { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual string State { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll need to store your relations independently to connect addresses and users/customers/agencies if you want to be able to use the same address for all types.  This involves introducing a new table that only stores ID pairs, and making that the storage location for your relationship.

You can map collections as many-to-many and use the table method to name your link table. Your mapping would look something like:

```
public UserMap : ClassMap<User> {
  Id (u => u.Id);
  Map (u => u.Name);
  HasManyToMany (u => u.Addresses).Table ("UsersXAddresses");
}
```

You'll need a similar link table for customers and agencies.

Comment: Could you tell me more about how to mapping between List of address, User and UsersXAddresses? Some example maps would be helpful.

Comment: Your other classes would need an identical map, but named differently.  And the Address is just calls to Id and Map for the respective properties.

Answer (score 1):

In the constructor for your mapping class, map the link using the `HasMany` method. `HasMany` will create a *one-to-many* relationship. `HasManyToMany` will create a *many-to-many* relationship.

**For example:** `HasMany(x => x.Address).LazyLoad();`

This will create a one-to-many relationship between the `User` class and the `Address` class.

For the many-to-many, you will also need to specify the table name and if you so desire, the left and right side table mappings.

**For example:** `HasManyToMany(x => x.Address).Table("AddressToUser").ParentKeyColumn("AddressId").ChildKeyColumn("UserId").LazyLoad();`

If you decide that you want to set up a distinction between a `UserAddress` and an `AgencyAddress` (where these are sub-classes of Address) - you can use the `DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn` method in the `AddressMap` class so the FNH knows to create an extra column in order to determine which type of object to create.

**For example:** `DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("Type").AlwaysSelectWithValue();`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use [FNH Automapping](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping) to map these classes "as is".

It will handle **all** the relationships in your object model.

I believe it will put all the addresses in a single Address table as you desire, but can't say for sure.